# Connection to Port 22 refused

Tags: 14.04, ssh, amazon-ec2

We have an issue in our LAN network which do not allow us to connect through Port 22 to servers outside our network. I am trying to use SSH to connect to EC2 instance in Amazon. Since, SSH connected through Port 22, I am not able to go ahead with it as it indicates: "Connection refused".

Is there anyway I can connect to the instance under such circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. Amazon EC2 [does not offer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=342545) browser based console access. They have a [Java client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/vmlaunch/step-2-connect-to-instance.html), but I guess it is using port 22 too.

You will have either to get the port 22 open for outgoing connection or find workaround a relay and/or reverse SSH tunnels or use tools like [Corkscrew](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HTTP_tunneling) punching holes through http proxies. In the latter case, you have to understand that it may breach corporate policies or reason behind the port 22 is closed in first place.

Comment: I do not have the required points to vote yout answer. But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Install in the machine that is going to receive your files

command: sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Comment: I'm not sure that this will help as port 22 (the SSH) port is blocked, so I don't think this would help, as they can't access the machine, so installing something and changing the default SSH port wouldn't be possible